Input element is not re-rendered
The input element is not re-rendered, the use case is that when the user enters some text the current date is filled into the input element via the 'value' attribute. See the code below.
@page "/"

<label>Text Binding check:</label>
<input type="text" value="@TextData" @onchange="OnChange_Text" />
<br />

<br />
<label>Text Dummy:</label>
<input type="text" value="dummy" />

@code
{
    public string? TextData { get; set; } = "12-12-2022";

    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void OnChange_Text(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        TextData = GetValue(e.Value?.ToString());

        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }

    private string GetValue(string? strValue)
    {
        return strValue switch
        {
            "test" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
            "data" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
            "nash" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
            _ => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
        };
    }
}

If the user enters the same text or any text again, the date is not rendered in the input element the second time. Even with StateHasChanged() and ShouldRender set to true, the value is not rendered.

So as per the Blazor mechanism the element is not really changed so the render tree will not render the input element to DOM. How can I solve this problem and how can I re-render the element that has not changed?. I thought SateHasChanged() and ShouldRender refresh the UI, it doesn't care about the element difference.

I'm assuming this is an Interactive page.
Use @bind and @bind:after.  Let binding and the UI event handler do the work.
The bind callback [to set TextData] is a UI event.  It sets the value and then calls the registered after method.  Finally it calls StateHasChanged to render the new state.
I've modified the dates produced and formatting so it's easier to see the different results.
@page "/"

<label>Text Binding check:</label>
<input type="text" @bind="TextData" @bind:after="OnChange_Text" />
<br />

<br />
<label>Text Dummy:</label>
<input type="text" value="@EnteredValue" />

@code
{
    public string? TextData { get; set; } = "12-Dec-2022";
    public string? EnteredValue;

    private void OnChange_Text()
    {
        this.EnteredValue = this.TextData;
        this.TextData = GetValue(this.TextData);
    }

    private string GetValue(string? strValue)
    {
        return strValue switch
        {
            "test" => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
            "data" => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
            "nash" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"),
            _ => DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
        };
    }
}

An explanation of why the original code didn't work.
It's complicated, but your problem is caused by synchronisation issues between the various DOMs when you modify the actual DOM in an edit element.
First Change
Starting state:

Actual DOM: 12-12-2022
Virtual DOM: 12-12-2022
Blazor Rendered DOM: 12-12-2022
TextData : 12-12-2022

When you change the Actual DOM to "Fred"

Actual DOM: Fred
Virtual DOM: 12-12-2022
Blazor Rendered DOM: 12-12-2022
TextData : 12-12-2022

When the onChange UI event completes:

Actual DOM: Fred
Virtual DOM: 12-12-2022
Blazor Rendered: 12-12-2022
TextData : Today

After the UI event render:

Actual DOM: Fred
Virtual DOM: 12-12-2022
Blazor Rendered: Today
TextData : Today

At the completion of the render the Renderer runs the diffing engine, detects the difference and send the updates to the actual DOM.

Actual DOM: Today
Virtual DOM: Today
Blazor Rendered: Today
TextData : Today

Second Change
Now we edit the input to "Fred" again.

Actual DOM: Fred
Virtual DOM: Today
Blazor Rendered DOM: Today
TextData : Today

When the onChange UI event completes:

Actual DOM: Fred
Virtual DOM: Today
Blazor Rendered DOM: Today
TextData : Today

After the UI event render:

Actual DOM: Fred
Virtual DOM: Today
Blazor Rendered DOM: Today
TextData : Today

At the completion of the render the Renderer runs the diffing engine, detects no difference and does nothing.  The actual DOM isn't updated.

Actual DOM: Fred
Virtual DOM: Today
Blazor Rendered DOM: Today
TextData : Today

You can use my solution, or add a workaround to your code by changing to this OnChange_Text:
    private async Task OnChange_Text(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set to nonsense value so the diffing engine sees the change
        TextData = "  ";
        // yield and let the UI event handler render the component
        await Task.Yield();
        // set to the nee value
        TextData = GetValue(e.Value?.ToString());
        // final UI event handler render will happen here
    }


aka Shaun Thanks for the solution. But why didn’t my code work as expected?. bind also sets the value of the property to the ‘value’ attribute and it re-renders the element right ?

See additional commentary to answer why.

Thanks for the detailed explanation..

Personally, I would avoid using JS when working with Blazor unless you really can't find an alternative or viable solution. Blazor already provides everything so we can stay with C#.
First of all you're gonna need interactivity for your page or else changes won't be rendered (at least for newer .NET and blazor versions). This can be activated using the following line @rendermode InteractiveServer.
Why don't you use the standard InputText component? Here you can bind the value to your property and update it directly. This also lets Blazor know that something has changed. StateHasChanged should only be called if needed as Blazor knows when changes occured (different story on child components).
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>SO Test</PageTitle>

<label>Text Binding check:</label>
<InputText @bind-Value="@TextData" />
<br />

<br />
<label>Text Dummy:</label>
<input type="text" value="dummy" />

@code
{
    private string? _text;

    private string? TextData
    {
        get => _text ?? "12-12-2022";
        set
        {
            _text = value switch
                    {
                        "test" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                        "data" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                        "nash" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                        _      => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
                    };
        }
    }
}

If you don't want to have the logic directly in the property, then you can also outsource it to a method and use the corresponding attributes in the InputText component (but in my opinion it looks a little less attractive)
// removed for brevity
<label>Text Binding check:</label>
<InputText id="name" Value="@TextData" ValueChanged="HandleValueChange" ValueExpression="() => TextData"></InputText>
<br />

// removed for brevity

@code
{
    private string? TextData { get; set; } = "12-12-2022";

    private void HandleValueChange(string? obj)
    {
        TextData = obj switch
                   {
                       "test" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                       "data" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                       "nash" => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                       _      => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
                   };
    }
}


private **async** void OnChange_Text(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    TextData = GetValue(e.Value?.ToString());

    **await** InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}

Of course, this is not the way to achieve the functionality that you are looking at. Simply use @bind-Value and @bind-Value:after

This might due to an optimization in blazor component rendering. I had a test in my side with your codes and I also ofound that the origin value for TextData is 12-12-2022, and then when we enter data in the input field, TextData will be changed to DataTime.Now which is 26-08-2024. The next time we change the input value, it will be changed to 26-08-2024 which doesn't change the value indeed. Then might due to somewhat optimization, even if we call StateHasChanged(), it won't re-render the page.
My workaround is using JS to update the DOM directly.
<input type="text" id="testInput" value="@TextData" @onchange="OnChange_Text" />

private void OnChange_Text(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    TextData = GetValue(e.Value?.ToString());
    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setInputValue", "testInput", TextData); 
}

And put js below just behind <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> in _Layout.cshtml since your tag is blazor server. If what you have is blazor web app, then it shall be <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script> which is in App.razor.
<script>
    window.setInputValue = (elementId, value) => {
        //alert(elementId);//for test purpose
        //alert(value);
        document.getElementById(elementId).value = value;
    };
</script>


You don't need to resort to JS Interop to do this.

Yeah, I just test within blazor server app and find this workaround, for better understanding if someone else prefer a JS method. Thank you for your sharing!

The moment you start changing sections of the DOM controlled by Blazor components, the actual DOM and the Blazor virtual DOM get out of sync, and you get all sorts of unexpected results.
